# Google Script to search a Sheet for a match then grab the next cells data and add it as a variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

Essentially what I have is a Google Form. This form has two column's Student email addresses and parent email addresses. A secretary is entering the Students email address in the form and I want the script to reference the sheet find the students email address in Column A and then grab the parents address next to it in column B and make it a variable.

Nothing seems to be working. In fact, I can't even get the script to add new data to the sheet.

The Triggers are set and the first two email addresses are working. I have also been able to look at the logs and found that it is referencing the sheet now and getting all of the data but is not going on to the for function or the if statement. Something appears to be wrong in that area.

```
 function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = e.response;
  var itemResponses = form.getItemResponses();
  var email = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var firstName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var lastName = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var assetTag = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var deviceIssue = itemResponses[4].getResponse();
  var description = itemResponses[5].getResponse();
  var building = itemResponses[6].getResponse();
  var helpDesk = 'Me@domain.com';

  var subject = 'Testing';
  var body = 'Making sure part of the Script has worked. ';

  MailApp.sendEmail(helpDesk, subject, body)
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)


  var statusSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15p9jsYIzvyMgok2pWkhYJYQZpSvqHO31Ugyn5mzXZD4").getSheetByName("Current");
  var data = statusSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
      for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ 
        if(data[n][0].toString().match(email)==email){ var parentEmail = data[n][1].getText();
      }
      Logger.log(data)

MailApp.sendEmail(parentEmail, subject, body)
}
```

Comment: Which is this script bound to your google form or spreadsheet? And did you set a trigger for "onFormSubmit()"? This script need to bound to google form. Since the form submit using "response" is "Installable", a trigger has to be set.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

Comment: Yes the Script is on the Form side and has a trigger set. The first two emails get sent but there is a problem with the SpreadsheetApp.openByID ..... The error report I got this morning stated it cannot find function openByID in object SpreadsheetApp Which is confusing seeing as how I'm using this same function in another script.

Comment: I fixed it! I feel like an idiot. the variable is set within the {} of the for statement so I needed to do my functions within there for it to work. after the var parentEmail I just entered down and setup the email before closing the } .... All Good I just needed to think it through!